# Where are the Drupal performance settings stored in the database?

Tags: drupal-6

I'm trying to find where in the database (tablename.fieldname) the settings such as "Caching mode" that appear on the Performance settings screen (/admin/settings/performance) are stored.

I've looked in the cache* tables, system, variable and performance* tables.

Answer (score 2):

I used the `variable_get()` function which returns all the variables stored in the variables table.

Answer (score 1):

These fields are in the "variables" table. You have to save the settings screen at least once for variables to appear.

Answer (score 1):

In the file `modules/system/system.admin.inc`, inside the function `system_performance_settings` you can see how the "Performance settings" form is created. Check the `#default` attributes: there are calls to `variable_get`, so some settings are stored in the `variables` table.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `variable_get('preprocess_css')` and `variable_get('preprocess_js')` to retrieve the information needed, since they are stored in the variables table.

You could simply set them yourself:

- `variable_set('preprocess_css', 1)` for 'on'
- `variable_set('preprocess_css', 0)` for 'off'

Maybe best set them inside settings.php by adding on of the two following lines simply at the end:

- `$conf['preprocess_css'] = 1;` for 'on'
- `$conf['preprocess_css'] = 0;` for 'off'